# Open DrRacket .rkt with emacs

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

Is it possible to run smoothly files saved by `DrRacket`?

for example if I save the following lines in a file called `test.rkt` with `DrRacket` and want to run it with `emacs`. How would I do this?

```
(require lang/htdp-intermediate)

; this is a test ; and a box comment-out with a box

;example
(check-expect (doubleN 2) 4)

;define
(define (doubleN nat)
(* 2 nat))

(doubleN 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:

1. Install geiser in emacs following the [instructions](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_2.html#Installation) on the Geiser website.
2. Open the file `test.rkt` in emacs.
3. Geiser mode should be active. If not use `M-x geiser-mode` and follow the prompts.
4. Press `C-c C-a` to start/enter the REPL and load `test.rkt` as the module.
5. If you make changes to `test.rkt` in its emacs buffer, save the changes with `C-x C-s` **before** reloading the module into the REPL with `C-c C-a`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did everything in the list and it works... only the first time. It seem that I cannot the above code twice. as it tells: doubleN: this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined.

Comment: @DJJ The issue may be related to using `lang\htdp-intermediate` because of module definitions. The student language may not behave as Geiser expects on the reload since it does not have the `#lang` reader syntax.

Comment: I removed  but (require lang/htdp-intermediate), the problem persists.

Comment: @DJJ Do you have #lang racket` at the top of the file? Have you restarted emacs?